# Rearrange XML tags in Talend

Tags: xml, talend

What is the appropriate way in Talend to rearrange tags in xml files?

Assuming that I have the following XML structure:

```
<Webexport>
  <employee> 
    <id>6789</id>  
    <name>Peter</name>  
    <anotherid>6789</anotherid>  
  </employee>
</Webexport>
```

What talend components with which configuration shall be used to rearrange the structure of the tags as follows:

```
<Webexport>
  <employee> 
    <idinfo>
      <id>6789</id>
      <anotherid>6789</anotherid>
    </idinfo>
    <name>Peter</name>  
  </employee>
</Webexport>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tXMLMap and create a new XML mapping of the document.

[image]

Comment: If I would like to add another subelement under the idinfo tag. Is this also the correct place to do it? Just create subelement of idinfo in the output table of tXMLMap?

Comment: Yep. Any other XML transformations are usually done in this component.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tFileInputXML to read for a loop path and then using tAdvancedFileOutputXML you can adjust add sub-elements, attributes to your xml. While defining schema xml tree for tAdvancedFileOutputXML  you can decide what to use as loop element.

[image]

Comment: Can you give me a hint for the configuration of the tFileInputXML component to read for a loop? At the moment the schema of my input xml file consist of one column "payload" of Type "Document". This component I connect to tAdvancedFileOutputXML by a flow? In the tAdvancedFileOutputXML I don't know how to map to reach the desired result.

Comment: added image - see if this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to apply xslt translations to your original XML. There is a tXslt component which does the job.

Comment: Could you give an example how to realize the requirement given above with the tXslt component?

Comment: It's plain xslt. Talend just applies it, so the magic happens through xslt transformation. For more info, please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289398/copy-and-rearrange-xml-nodes-with-xslt